# Submit button conflicts with to different functions

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, button

Friends i am stuck with a strange issue and i need your suggests to fix it.

In my Master page I am using a Search box with a button, it works fine in all pages except the "Request Quote page" which have a form for users to fill.
If a person is on the Request Quote page and want to search using the searchbox in head section, it do not take the user to the search result page, instead it triggers the form validations of the "RequestQuote Form"

Here are my codes;
**Search Box from MasterPage Head Section**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="SearchBox" runat="server" CssClass="search_textbox" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton ID="SearchButton" runat="server" onclick="SearchButton_Click" />

protected void ISearchButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{ Response.Redirect("Search-commercial.aspx?Zip=" + SearchBox.Text); }
```

Some Codes from **Request Quote Page**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton ID="QuoteButton" runat="server" onclick="QuoteButton_Click" />

protected void IQuoteButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{ SqlDataSource3.Insert();
  Response.Redirect("InstallerThanks.aspx");        
}
```

Friends any idea where i made the mistake?

Comment: What does this mean: "it goes to the first textbox field"? If the user clicks `SearchButton` the handler `IQuoteButton_Click` will be called instead of `ISearchButton_Click`? Or do you mean on enter key pressed?

Comment: It might be helpful to post the relevant bits of the html that is rendered.  Seems like you have a conflicting id or name in a control to me.

Comment: when a person click the search button, instead of going to search result page, it trigers the Validations of the Request Quote form.

Comment: ok i found the solution by luck, i disabled all the form validators by default unless a user click the Submit Quote button, since all validators are disabled so there is no conflict with my search box button, hope this solution can help others having same issue

Comment: @AliKhan: You should use [ValidationGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.validationgroup.aspx) to avoid this issue.

Comment: Thank you so much TIM, you gave the best solution, the info you gave will help me in future also, once again big thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of disabling all validators you should use different [ValidationGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.validationgroup.aspx).